# Forward proxy for webservices with SSL client certs

Tags: linux, ssl, proxy, web-services

I have lots of servers which access various external webservices, most of which use SSL, some of which require client certificates. I would like to centralize the configuration of client certs and dissociate the presentation layer from the underlying servers.

While I could use Squid to proxy the requests, I can't see from the docs how to tell Squid to select a client certificate specific to the target webservice. Is this possible?

One approach would be to maintain a gang of stunnel instances beyond the Squid proxy, then configure the client software to use http requests with a URL rewriter to route the request via the appropriate stunnel instance, however that will break if I get a XML response referencing a HTTPS DTD (unless I rewrite the content with a full MITM).

Is there another solution?

**update**

The problem with re-writing 'https' to 'http' is that it then breaks any additional resources with an http URI - since the protocol adapter will then convert these back to https!

I came across [this article](https://blackdot.be/2012/07/ssl-client-certificate-injection-using-reverse-and-forward-proxies/) which addressed the problem of adding a client certificate to a proxied connection - which is potentially a solution. But does require that the client be configured to use a proxy, there are also problems around naming things and how to get it working with split DNS. Admittedly not huge problems, but it got me thinking that what I am describing here is the pattern used by most CDN providers - hence I am currently considering using Apache Traffic Server as the intermediate component - this allows use of split DNS, seperate SSL channels between the client and the origin, and client certificates for the communication with the origin server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging in further I decided to use back to back instances of pound. I also considered using stunnel or haproxy, but pound deals with the SSL stuff and has a basic capacity for manipulating http headers.

Answer (score 0):

Squid-in-the-middle decryption and encryption of straight CONNECT and transparently redirected SSL traffic, using configurable CA certificates.

http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/SslPeekAndSplice

Comment: How does this tell Squid how to select a client certificate specific to the target webservice?

Comment: Oh, it seems they have not yet created all ACLs you need. My apologies.